# Which coder should I use to code a long property using NSCoder?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nscoder

I have an object I must encode using encodewithcoder but it's a 'long' number and I'm not sure if I must encode it like a simple int, a int32 or a int64. Apple's documentation doesn't seems to be useful for me to figure out since it never refers to 'long' type.

Which coder is the proper one?.

Thank you

Comment: Assuming its impossible to change your property to a known width primitive like int32_t or similar?

Comment: This property is defined in the documentation I've received from the client (a big enterprise). I really don't know what is this property supposed to store.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For iOS, a `long` is 32-bits, same as an `int`. `long long` gives you 64-bits.

```
long someVar = 42l;
[someEncoder encodeInt32:someVar forKey:@"someKey"];
```

Comment: Wow!. That was fast!. Thank you.

Comment: Hmm, encoding a `long` with `encodeInt32` gives me a loss of precision warning - but not when using `encodeInt64`.